# SQL Server: How to remove partially empty rows from table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, partial

I have an odd scenario and could not find a solution in google or a question similar in stack overflow:

Here is my table:

table1  (currently)

```
category col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  totalsum
--------------------------------------------------------------
a         12    25   null  null  null  null   null   $20
a         12    25    34   null  null  null   null   $20
b         57    93    72   63     99   null   null   $50
b         57    93    72   63     99   107    null   $50
b         57    93    72   63     99   107    32     $50
```

I need to remove the partial / incomplete rows and save the more complete row to a new table so that my table will now be this (I need to keep the rows with the least number of nulls) but I am having trouble filtering out the incomplete rows and isolating the more complete rows.

what I need

```
category col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  totalsum
--------------------------------------------------------------
a         12    25    34   null  null  null   null   $20
b         57    93    72   63     99   107    32     $50
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Is the latest row for each category always have more details than previous row of same category?

Comment: No, that is not a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to sort by those columns together with a row_number():

```
select *
from (
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY col2 desc, col3 desc, col4 desc, col5 desc, col6 desc, col7 desc, col8 desc) rn
from table1) i
where i.rn = 1
```

test code:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 'a' category  ,12 col2 ,25 col3, null col4, null col5, null col6 ,null col7, null col8, 20 totalsum
UNION ALL SELECT 'a' ,12 ,25 ,34 ,null ,null ,null ,null ,20
UNION ALL SELECT 'b' ,57 ,93 ,72 ,63 ,99 ,null ,null ,50
UNION ALL SELECT 'b' ,57 ,93 ,72 ,63 ,99 ,107 ,null ,50
UNION ALL SELECT 'b' ,57 ,93 ,72 ,63 ,99 ,107 ,32 ,50
)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY col2 DESC, col3 DESC, col4 DESC, col5 DESC, col6 DESC, col7 DESC, col8 DESC) rn
FROM cte) i
WHERE i.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT category,
       MAX(col2) AS col2,
       MAX(col3) AS col3,
       MAX(col4) AS col4,
       MAX(col5) AS col5,
       MAX(col6) AS col6,
       MAX(col7) AS col7,
       MAX(col8) AS col8,
       MAX(totalsum) AS totalsum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY category
```

This approach would work well assuming you are OK with accepting the largest non `NULL` value per column, per category.  This pivot trick works because the `MAX()` function in SQL Server ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: what if the latest row of category has modified column value which is less than previous row of same category?

Comment: @chindiralasampathkumar Then this simple approach would fail.  But did the OP's data imply this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

May be something as this:

```
select * from table1 as t1 
where not exists(
                select 1 from table1 as t2 
                where(t1.id!=t2.id)and(t1.category=t2.category)
                and((t1.col1=t2.col1)or(is_null(t1.col1)and(not is_null(t2.col1))and...
                )
```

But, for you can exclude same rows from t1 and t2 each row must have unique id, see (t1.id!=t2.id).
Main idea - exclude rows, which has more relevant copy (more NOT null fields).